# Cant save class using SharedPreference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want to save my class object using SharedPreferences also i have Gson libary.
My code is:

i declare in global:

```
SharedPreferences  mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Then i save my class:

```
         Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
             Gson gson = new Gson();
             String json = gson.toJson("Copy");
             prefsEditor.putString("Copy", json);
             prefsEditor.commit();
```

And then i load my class:

```
             Gson gson = new Gson();
             String json = mPrefs.getString("Copy", "");
             Copy obj = gson.fromJson(json, Copy.class);
```

And when i running my app it crash instantly. Also in LogCat i have java.NullPointException.

Comment: You are using it wrong. Why are you passing `"Copy"` to `toJson` ?

Comment: Full stacktrace would be helpful, instead of needing to guess as in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences  mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
```

I'm guessing you're declaring and initializing a member variable here as indicated by the `m` prefix. You're doing it too early. You cannot use the activity as a `Context` until `onCreate()`. Move the initialization there.

Comment: Ye its better now i get crash and nullpoint when i click load button when i try to load again my class